# adding a dynamic button on a MCGrid

Tags: php, atk4

i want to modify the line in the code below ($g->addColumn('button','check_out') to $g->addColumn('button','check_in')  if the field instock is 'N'

This way the button calls a different function depending on if the tool is instock.

I do have the functions in the model as well already.

```
<?php
class page_index extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $page=$this;

        $g=$page->add('MVCGrid');

        $tool=$g->setModel('Tools',
            array('number','name','description','instock'));

        $g->addColumn('button','check_out');
        $g->addPaginator(20);
        $g->dq->order('number asc');

        if($_GET['check_out']){
            $tool->loadData($_GET['check_out']);
            $tool->check_out()->update();
            $g->js()->reload()->execute();
        }
        if($_GET['check_in']){
            $tool->loadData($_GET['check_in']);
            $tool->check_in()->update();
            $g->js()->reload()->execute();
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into implementation of format_button() inside "atk4/lib/Grid" and create your own function just like that. You'll also need to extend "Grid" to add this function.

You will also need to look into init_button() function which slaps jQuery UI button() function on the whole column.